# Как в программировании устроены события (Events)?

Tags: python, события

Предположим, мне нужно отследить какое-то событие, например сообщение в `discord` или нажатие какой-либо клавиши и т.п.

Все это я могу реализовать в бесконечном цикле, который каждые X мс будет проверять *`пришло ли сообщение / нажата ли сейчас кнопка`* и т.п.

Но это считается неправильным подходом, ведь для этих целей существуют обработчики событий, которые сразу же уведомят меня о том, что произошло нужное мне событие.

---

**Вопрос в том, как же устроены эти обработчики внутри?** По сути для ожидания события так или иначе требуется цикл с проверкой условий? Или они устроены как-то по другому?

*Я пытался найти информацию об этом, но везде обнаруживал только лишь уроки по применению событий в коде или созданию своего события на основе уже имеющегося класса.*

Comment: Это зависит от того, что конкретно наблюдается - умеет ли оно "тыкать" программу по наступлению события или не умеет. Если API того же дискорда умеет сам слать события в какой-нибудь вебсокет или вебхук - тогда ничего делать не надо, просто ждать входящих данных. Ну а если не умеет, то таки придётся в цикле проверять нужные условия

Comment: почитайте про решение "сигнал - слот " в qt, это как раз то, что вам надо. В qt  есть свой eventLoop, который следит за вашими событиями.Он работает отдельным потоком и при получении какого-то сигнала вызывает какой-то обработчик. Проще говоря обработчик внутри в большинстве случаев работы с каким-то интерфейсом(view) отдельным потоком следит за сигналами и согласно этим сигналам отдельно передает запрос на слот, который знает что делать при нажатии той или иной кнопки, это если говорить о программных обработчиках. В случае с аппаратными прерываниями всё несколько иначе.

Comment: События устроены довольно по-разному. Часть событий вообще инициируются на уровне операционной системы и там нет никакого цикла. Грубо говоря, в любой момент может прийти сигнал от контроллера, который вызовет некий код ОС без всяких циклов. Как бы такой `callback` сработает. Но есть и с циклами, всякое есть. Но в любом случае это устроено сложнее, чем обычные циклы с `sleep` и проверкой условия.

Comment: Если вас интересуют аппаратные прерывания, то они поступают прямиком в процессор, снимая ту задачу(сохраняя само собой контекст и прочую инфу предыдущего процесса), которая выполнялась на момент прихода. Процессор, идёт в "верхнюю часть" драйвера, где вызывается непосредственно - функция обрабочик("нижняя часть").

подробнее linux device drivers3 ,есть и на русском. Извините за верхнюю и нижнюю часть драйвера, не знал как иначе сделать наглядную абстракцию

Comment: Да, вы правы, в основном они устроены на основе цикла. Вот, например, описание цикла событий Tcl/Tk. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+event+loop